# Is EHIC card enough for Erasmus students in Germany?

Tags: germany, health-insurance, erasmus, ehic

A friend of mine is going on exchange under the Erasmus programme in Germany. She is a EU-citizen and has EHIC card. Does she need another health insurance or is the EHIC card enough for her stay?

Comment: I took the liberty to retag the question, but I don't feel 100% sure about it. Still I think that we don't need a seperate tag [tag:ehic] since it's reasonably covered by [tag:health-insurance] and [tag:eu-citizens]. I'm certainly open to discussion.

Comment: @tohecz I rejected it. I agree that we probably don't need the ehic tag, but note that eu residents and (non eu citizens) can also have ehic card

Comment: I'm not sure that the fact they can have it means it is not primarily about EU citizens, as long as the situation is typical for EU citizens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Erasmus, the EHIC card from the home country is enough. During her stay, your friend is still officially registered as a student in your home country so that is where she is registered for health insurance. In addition, EHIC card entitles one to necessary health care in all EU countries so she is covered in case of an emergency. Still, it can be a good idea to get a complete medical checkup before leaving as that is something that is not, to my knowledge, covered in other EU countries.

Comment: I think you lose your insurance if you get employed (even small part time job) on the EHIC card. Can somebody confirm it? It may be iportant to know.

Comment: @Smiling_Man That might depend on particular detail. For example, under certain circumstances, you are not required to pay health insurance from your part time job (typically if you earn below certain threshold) and then you would keep your student EHIC card. If you are however required to pay health insurance then you will have to unregister from health insurance in your home country and register in the country where you work.